# Setting a source property of Image in Silverlight using converter

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I have a page where I want to display images in a control Template. For this I only get the Image name to show. So I am using a converter to return BitmapImage like this:

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

in the XAML binding i have:

```
Image Source="{Binding ThumbNail,Converter={StaticResource MapImagePath}}"/>
```

For some reason i am not able to see the image at all.

I have changed my image extension to .jpeg but still not working.

Am i doing some thing wrong or suggest me if I am wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the image built as resource in your project ?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by resource in my project. But i have dragged and dropped onto my XAMl page.

Comment: Where have you added this image file in your project.check if build action is set to Resource

Comment: build action is set to content. How that differs???

Comment: Is your converter actually returning the image ? How are you referring to the image pack uri.

Comment: my converter is not returning image but just path. I pass image name with extention and converter returns /images/imagename.extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your converter so that it returns an instance of `BitmapImage`. Your converter is currently returning a string or a Uri however the actual type for the `Source` property is `ImageSource`.

The conversion of a string to a `BitmapImage` is some magic that the XamlParser does for us but when we supply the value using a Converter we need to give it the correct type.

Comment: even after i change it to retun BitMapImage instance it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ImageFailed event to check if there is any exception being thrown while loading the image. Usually you get AG_E_NETWORK_ERROR if there is any network problem while loading images from internet.

I had faced this problem while running the Silverlight application from file system which is default in Visual Studio 2010 using the built in web server. I moved the hosting web application to local IIS server and then the images were visible.

Answer (score 0):

1. First change your image property to content.[Right click to your image, go to property and change build action from Resource to content
2. Now suppose we have to "/Resources/Images/1.png" file.

Write code something like below in your converter.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,  System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    Uri uri = new Uri(@"Resources/Images/1.png", UriKind.Relative);
    bitmap .SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(uri).Stream);
    return bitmap ;
}
```